# Button in a fragment for switching to another activity - does not work

Tags: java, android

I want to create a button in a fragment for switching to another activity. I did everything but the button just does not respond. An animation appears that it is being pressed, but the method itself does not work. For clarity, I made a toast, it also does not work. How to make the button work?

> ActionsFragment.java

```
public class ActionsFragment extends Fragment {
    public ActionsFragment(){

    }

    Button Button_Add;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actions, container, false);
        Button_Add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_Add);
        Button_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.button_Add:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActionsFragment.this.getActivity(),Action_AddActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                        default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;

    }
}
```

> My xml file

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: remove switch statement from your code and use get activity instead of Fragment.this.getActivity

Comment: Are you getting any exception in android logcat? Please check and post if any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call **startActivity(intent)** from activity context. so either pass the context to the fragment when you create it, or use

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The button itself does not work, the method has not yet been tested.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I see is that you are switching a View, by that manner you will be not able to pass to other activity. It's simple, just clear the code.
**Try this:**

```
button_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActionsFragment.this.getActivity(),Action_AddActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, nothing has changed, the button still does not work. I don’t think it is because of the code inside the onClick method